# Windows Service using a Class library with Log4net configuration

Tags: windows-services, log4net

I have a solution that includes a class library that has some log4net configuration using a RollingLogFileAppender. All this is setup in the app.config for the class library.
When I use the class library on the Console App I see the app.config is copied to the folder of the console app with the name of mylibrary.dll.config. And as soon as I run the exe, the log files appears there and starts logging.

But now I want to try to use the same library on a WindowsService. So I created a new project for a Windows Service, referenced the library, ... After I install the service I see it's working fine, but no logging is done from log4net. On the folder for the service I see the same config files as on the console app, using the same configurarion options for log4net, but no file is created when I start the service.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Seems a small change make this work. On the class library I added this line, specifically identifying the name of the config file

// Configure log4net using the .config file
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "mylibrary.dll.config", Watch = true)]